# Yii Framework not returning proper WebUser class with Yii-user extension

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have [Yii-User](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user) installed inside of Yii webapp. However, if I print out the User object using this: `Yii::app()->user` I get CWebUser class instead of the [Yii-user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user) extended class WebUser.

My main.php config is setup as below:

```
    ...
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'loginUrl' => '/user/login',
            'class' => 'WebUser',
         ),
    ),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have correctly configured configured the rest of the module:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
  'application.models.*',
  'application.components.*',
  'application.modules.user.models.*',
  'application.modules.user.components.*',
),
...
'modules'=>array(
        #...
       'user' => array ( ... )
 ),
```

If so, and it still doesn't work, try configuring the user component like this:

```
...
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'loginUrl' => '/user/login',
        'class' => 'application.modules.user.components.WebUser',
     ),
),
...
```

Comment: This the approach I took (which is listed in the documentation) and should work. I am not sure if it is an issue with other ext that I have or not. Though, I used [Installing Yii Users and Rights in 5 easy steps](http://www.benjaminlhaas.com/blog/installing-yii-users-and-rights-5-steps) since I was looking at using the rights ext anyway. Some reason merging this with my current install using git fixed it.